# Limit the number of config sections

Tags: asp.net, web-config, config

In ASP.NET, when creating a custom config section, how do I limit the number of a particular section that can be declared?

For example, if in web.config, I repeat the appSettings section...

```
<appSettings /> 
<appSettings />
```

...I get an exception when the configuration loads.

If I do the same with my section...

```
<employer /> 
<employer />
```

...it allows it, but I don't want it to.

My section code (C#) looks like this:

```
    [ConfigurationProperty("employer", IsRequired = true)]
    public EmployerElement Employer
    {
        get
        {
            return (EmployerElement)this["employer"];
        }
        set
        { this["employer"] = value; }
    }
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think each configuration property can only appear once in a section. I tested it in my code and I got an exception. The above code is only a property. Can you post the completed code of config section and `EmployerElement` configuration element?

Comment: Sorry, my fault.  I had the configuration in an external file, so when it was updated it wasn't causing an automatic application re-start.  Obviously, duplicating <appSettings> in web.config was causing a restart.  I now get the error in both scenarios, so all is good.  Thanks.